# .htaccess ModRewrite with 2 parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

**@anubhava** provided an excellent answer for my previous question of doing an .htaccess internal rewrite with the below code, which worked for my one search query.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ /directory/%1? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

I wanted to make this a separate question since my next question is slightly different. How could I adapt this to also work with **two** parameters? For instance, I would also like `http://ipaddress/directory/file.php?id=47?name=value1` to redirect to `http://ipaddress/directory/47/value1`
**name=** can also be any combination of letters and numbers, like value1050, etc.

Thank you **@anubhava** for your previous answer above, and maybe there's a way to add on this **second parameter** as well?

Comment: You can't pass 2 `?` in your query string may be you need to use `&` to add more than one parameter in query string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you are segregating your query string values in `id=1234&name=value123` style, since passing 2 times query string will not be allowed, then you could try following, fix of your shown attempt.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&name=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^file\.php/?$ /directory/%1/%2? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/(.*)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Adding 1 more solution here, either use above OR use following one at a time only please.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/file\.php\?d=(\d+)&name=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /directory/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/(.*)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: The second solution seems to partially work. However, the CSS does not render on the page after the rewrite.

Comment: Nevermind, it was a CSS issue on my end! Is it possible to adapt this to also accept a **/** at the end of the url? So if users decide to add a backslash? Like `http://ipaddress/directory/47/value1/`

Comment: @ccc, you mean you want url `http://localhost:80/directory/file.php?id=47?name=value1` to be changed to `http://localhost:80/directory/47/value1/`? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: I just mean that if I had a **/** to the end of the url, then no data is requested at all. So I was wondering if it's possible to add an exception for if a **/** is or isn't included at the end of the url.

Comment: @ccc, you could try `Directoryindex off` option before RewriteEngine on option. It's very late night here, I am on mobile so couldn't test it, try it out once.